# Cygwin - auto install OpenSSH server

Tags: cygwin, openssh

I am wondering if there is a way that can help me not only install cygwin automatically but also help me establish OpenSSH server by using cygwin.
Is it possible to do it in one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it will require at least two scripts.

A silent install of cygwin is  [sort of possible, but tedious](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-03/msg00877.html).  It requires you going through the installation process at least partly manually once.  Near the end of that link is a section "- If you want to configure something automatically after running setup.exe,", which you will have to adapt to complete the post-install setup required for running an [ssh server in cygwin](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html).

Answer (score 2):

Silent install cygwin openssh and apt-cyg:

```
setup -q -D -s http://mirrors.xmission.com/cygwin -l C:\cygwin -L C:\cygwin -P wget,git,git-svn,openssh
C:\cygwin\bin\wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
C:\cygwin\bin\install apt-cyg /bin
C:\cygwin\bin\mkpasswd -l > C:\cygwin\etc\passwd    
C:\cygwin\bin\mkgroup -l > C:\cygwin\etc\group
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -c "/bin/ssh-user-config -y -p paswordforusersshd"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=SSH dir=in action=allow protocol=tcp localport=22
net start sshd
```

Comment: i dont think it creates the windows service successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question that already has a marked answer; however, for others searching, I'd like to contribute an additional answer for Windows admins that want an easy-to-use package that automatically installs and configures the Cygwin port of OpenSSH on Windows:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/CygSSH

It uses Cygwin v3 so it doesn't require a dedicated service account (the service runs as SYSTEM).

The intent is to provide a convenient packaging of OpenSSH and rsync that would be (relatively) convenient to install and use on Windows machines, so it has some defaults and capabilities that are more Windows-centric:

- Installer supports silent installation and adding to the system path
- PowerShell is the remote interactive shell (either Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core)
- It creates an SSH Users local group for authentication and sets that by default in `sshd_config`; nested groups are supported (e.g., if you want to manage the membership via GPO)
- It supports granting sftp-only access to accounts
- It includes rsync

The latest version of the installer requires 64-bit Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012R2 or newer.

Note that this installer does not provide general-purpose Cygwin install; the intent is to provide an easy-to-use prepackaged OpenSSH for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use this, specifically for the task you're referring to. Scroll down to the Batch script titled, *Deploy Cygwin and OpenSSH*...

[J2897's Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/u/J2897)

It will automatically set up Public Key Authentication too. So all you should have to do is add your public key to the server's *authorized_keys* file.